# XSLT to check for unique values in XML

Tags: xml, xslt

I have an unordered XML and the goal is to use XSLT to transform the XML like shown below. How do I approach this? Do I traverse the XML first to check for unique stores and then traverse the XML a second time to insert the dates where it matches the store?
Initial XML:

```
<transactions>
 <transaction>
  <store>2</store>
  <date>10.10.2020</date>
 </transaction>
 <transaction>
  <store>1</store>
  <date>11.10.2020</date>
 </transaction>
 <transaction>
  <store>2</store>
  <date>12.10.2020</date>
 </transaction>
</transactions>
```

Expected output:

```
<transactions>
 <shop id="1">
  <date>11.10.2020</date>
 </shop>
 <shop id="2">
  <date>10.10.2020</date>
  <date>12.10.2020</date>
 </shop>
</transactions>
```

Comment: What is your XSLT version?

Comment: This is a [grouping](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/xslt-grouping/info) question. Do a search - it's probably the most often asked XSLT question here. Note that answers are different for XSLT 1.0 or 2.0.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that it is XSLT 2.0...

**XML**

```
<transactions>
    <transaction>
        <store>2</store>
        <date>10.10.2020</date>
    </transaction>
    <transaction>
        <store>1</store>
        <date>11.10.2020</date>
    </transaction>
    <transaction>
        <store>2</store>
        <date>12.10.2020</date>
    </transaction>
</transactions>
```

**XSLT**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:template match="transactions">
        <transactions>
            <xsl:for-each-group select="transaction" group-by="store">
                <xsl:sort select="current-grouping-key()" order="ascending"/>
                <shop id="{store}">
                    <xsl:copy-of select="current-group()/date"/>
                </shop>
            </xsl:for-each-group>
        </transactions>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Output**

```
<transactions>
  <shop id="1">
    <date>11.10.2020</date>
  </shop>
  <shop id="2">
    <date>10.10.2020</date>
    <date>12.10.2020</date>
  </shop>
</transactions>
```

Comment: Thank you. How does it look for XSLT 1.0?

Comment: @CoconutDrinkByTheBeach, just look it up for the Muenchian method.